# XMLHttpRequest fails on an https page on flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have  a simple code for an XMLHttpRequest in a javascript, for a web page that is deployed over flask.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){}
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:"+"5005"+"/"+"abcd", true);
xhr.send();
```

This works perfectly when the flask is deployed over HTTP and I can see the request on a local application listening on 5005. However when I enable HTTPS mode on flask, then this fails.

Note that I am still doing an HTTP post to the localhost.

The only difference between the two is that the webpage is displayed over HTTPS(URL has https://example.com instead of http://example.com).

When I check the web page source for both cases, they match.

I understand that the browser renders the page and executes the javascript code. However I do not understand why changing the flask mode to HTTPS disables this feature.

This behavior is common to Chrome, Safari and IE

Has anyone else experience a similar problem. Is this a security feature in browsers,( considering this as cross site scripting maybe)?

Cause I don't see why it should fail otherwise.

Comment: it's a "mixed content" issue ... a page served over `https` restricts what can be retrieved using `http` - your XHR is hard coded to use `http` which works fine in a page served over `http` but will not work in a page served over `https` - I would think a warning/error message would be shown in the developer tools console regarding this mixed content, can you see any such message in your developer tools console?

Comment: I see. So the only solution is to deploy my localhost application over https as well?

Comment: https for `localhost` is painful though

Comment: You gotta do what you gotta do :)